# Google Sheets: CountIf and Dates

Tags: google-sheets

Haven't gotten any help through the Google Product Forums, so I'll try here. I've never had issues with this before so not sure what I'm missing now. I can't seem to make a rather simple formula work and I have no idea why.

**For some reason, `=COUNTIF(SCHEDULE!$C$9:$C29,">="&B$2)` returns 0, when I'm expecting it to return 21.**

- In `B2` is the date "6/25/2018", which is actually a reference to
  `SCHEDULE!C2`.
- Am I just not understanding the logic correctly? "If the dates in `C9:C29` are after or equal to 6/25/2018, then count them."
- When I try it as `<=` it doesn't work either.
- I don't think there is an issue with the dates being formatted using `TEXT(B2,"MM/DD/YYYY")` because other formulas seem to be working fine.

Alternatively, I also tried using `SUM(QUERY)`, but that also got hung up when using the dates.

`=sum(query(SCHEDULE!A9:AB,"select count(F) where F='2004' and C >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(B2),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0))`

You can see a test version of the sheet [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/169GhvqL-rUJ9LhxWushOTi14fpEEXtO-hUmFTrfLorw/edit?usp=sharing).

I am working from the REF sheet.

You can see what I've tried in `Z6`, `Z7`, `Z8` and `AA6`.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. I'm not sure if it's the fact that some of the dates from the SCHEDULE page are rendered using TEXT, but I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ref!B2 is `TEXT(SCHEDULE!$C$2,"MM/DD/YYYY")`. You cannot compare text-that-looks-like-a-date to true dates.

The best option is to use `=SCHEDULE!$C$2` in REF!B2 and format the cell as `mm/dd/yyyy`.

The bandaid (dig a hole then fill it up) is to adjust your COUNTIF to,

```
=COUNTIF(SCHEDULE!$C$9:$C29,">="&DateValue(B$2))
```

Comment: Gotcha. That didn't quite work, but I was able to change all the text dates to datevalues in a helper column and got it to work as intended. Thanks!